# My Button Functions Are Not Working in my Python code

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Good Day,
I'm designing a simple eatery Gui in Python with the Tkinter library but my "Reset" and "Calculate Price" buttons don't work as they should. Please what could the problem be?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application (Frame):
    def __init__(self,anjie):
        super(Application,self).__init__(anjie)
        #getting the init() function in frame,the superclass
        #super is a function that takes two parameters: the name of your subclass i.e. Application and self
        self.grid() #allows grid function to work
        self.toppings=["sausage","pepperoni","chicken","mushroom","black olive","green pepper","red pepper","onion"]
        self.prices={"medium":9.99, "large":12.99, "x-large":14.99, "mid-topping":1.0, "large-topping":1.4, "xl-topping":1.8}
        self.checkbox=list(self.toppings)
        self.checkboxVar=list(self.toppings)
        self.create_widgets()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        menubar=Menu(self)
        filemenu=Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Quit",command=window.quit)
        
        filemenu.add_command(label="Submit",command=self.process)
        
            
        self.label1=Label(self,text="Select size: ")
        self.label1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.size=StringVar() #similar to name in html, groups similar elements together with variable self.size
        print(StringVar())
        
        self.radio1=Radiobutton(self,text="Medium",variable=self.size,value="Medium")
        self.radio1.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.radio1.select() #makes radio1 the default selected radio button
        
        self.radio2=Radiobutton(self,text="Large",variable=self.size,value="Large")
        self.radio2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
        self.radio2.select()
        
        self.radio3=Radiobutton(self,text="Extra Large",variable=self.size,value="X-Large")
        self.radio3.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)
        self.radio3.select()
        
        self.label2=Label(self,text="Select size: ")
        self.label2.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        
        
        line=2#last row number
        for i in range(len(self.toppings)):
            line+=1
            self.checkboxVar[i]=BooleanVar() #default value added is false
            self.checkboxVar[i]=Checkbutton(self,text=self.toppings[i], variable=self.checkboxVar[i])
            self.checkboxVar[i].grid(row=line,column=0,sticky=W)
            
        line+=1
        self.button1=Button(self,text="Reset",command=self.reset)
        self.button1.grid(row=line,column=0,sticky=E)
        self.button2=Button(self,text="Calculate Price",command=self.calculate)
        self.button2.grid(row=line,column=2)
        
        line+=1
        self.label3=Label(self,text="")
        self.label3.grid(row=line,column=0)
        
        line+=1
        self.label4=Label(self,text="Total: ")
        self.label4.grid(row=line,column=0,sticky=E)
        self.result=Entry(self,width=10)
        self.result.grid(row=line,column=1,sticky=W)
        
        window.config(menu=menubar)
        
    def process(self):
        print("This is the process to submit: ")
        
    def reset(self):
        self.radio1.select()
        for i in range(len(self.toppings)):
            self.checkbox[i].deselect()
        self.result.delete(0,END)
        
    def calculate(self):
        self.totalToppings=0
        for i in range(len(self.toppings)):
            if self.checkboxVar[i].get():
                self.totalToppings+=1
                        
            if self.size.get()=="Medium":
                self.price=self.prices["medium"]+(self.totalToppings * self.prices["mid-topping"])
            if self.size.get()=="Large":
                self.price=self.prices["large"]+(self.totalToppings*self.prices["large-topping"])
            if self.size.get()=="X-Large":
                self.price=self.prices["x-large"]+(self.totalToppings*self.prices["xl-topping"])
                
            
            str_price="{.2f}".format(self.price)
            self.result.delete(0,END)
            self.result.insert(END,str_price)
            
window=Tk()
window.title("Anjie\'s Pizza")
window.geometry("800x500") #WIDTH BY HEIGHT
app=Application(window)
app.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate any help regarding this. I did this with the Python tkinter library and my problem is that no result appears in the total entry.

Comment: If I run this and press the button labled "Calculate Price" I get the error message: `AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'` and for "Reset" I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'deselect'`. How do you run this that you can't see the error messages?

Comment: State clearly what are the expected results you want.

Comment: @acw1668 Calculate price should return the price of what they want to order. Reset should reset all check boxes

Comment: @Matthias I can clearly see the errors. My issue is that I don't know how to correct them. Hence why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

- Call `.select()` on all radio buttons, should only call `self.radio1.select()` initially
- Used `self.checkboxVar[i]` instead of `self.checkbox[i]`

```py
def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    #self.radio2.select()  # should not call
    ...
    #self.radio3.select()  # should not call
    ...
    line=2#last row number
    for i in range(len(self.toppings)):
        line+=1
        self.checkboxVar[i]=BooleanVar() #default value added is false
        ### should use self.checkbox[i]=... instead of self.checkboxVar[i]=...
        self.checkbox[i]=Checkbutton(self,text=self.toppings[i], variable=self.checkboxVar[i])  
        self.checkbox[i].grid(row=line,column=0,sticky=W)
    ...
```

- Used invalid float format `{.2f}`, should be `{:.2f}` instead:

```py
def calculate(self):
    ...
    str_price="{:.2f}".format(self.price)
    ...
```

Comment: I did that but I still have this error  "PY_VAR1
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ariel\OneDrive\Documents\400L\SIWES\NH PYTHON\newpython\eatery.py", line 89, in calculate
    if self.checkbox[i].get():
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get' ". My calculate price button still doesn't work however my reset button works

Comment: @AnjieLayo It is because you have changed `self.checkboxVar[i].get()` to `self.checkbox[i].get()` inside `calculate()` as well.  Look carefully that I have only changed two lines from `self.checkboxVar[i]` to `self.checkbox[i]` inside `create_widgets()` in my answer.

Comment: I did that and I have this error: "PY_VAR1
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ariel\OneDrive\Documents\400L\SIWES\NH PYTHON\newpython\eatery.py", line 89, in calculate
    if self.checkbox[i].get():
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get' "

Comment: Look carefully on the error, you have used `self.checkbox[i].get()`.  `self.checkboxVar[i].get()` should be used instead inside `calculate()`.

Comment: Yes this was what I did initially but my error is still similar: "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ariel\OneDrive\Documents\400L\SIWES\NH PYTHON\newpython\eatery.py", line 89, in calculate
    if self.checkboxVar[i].get():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' "

Comment: @AnjieLayo Did you follow the changes required in my answer exactly?  Seems like you have also changed the line `self.checkboxVar[i]=BooleanVar()` to `self.checkbox[i]=BooleanVar()` inside `create_widgets()` which I don't have in my answer.